# Почему не работает вычисления в методах класса в Swift

Tags: swift, переменные, методы

Я новичок не судите строго, что я не так в коде написал, что не складываться 2 числовых переменных

```
func zoo(x:Int, z:Int)->Int {

            print("Hello-\(x) \(z)") 
            return z+x
```

Вот сам код полной программы

```
class Z{
    func zoo(x:Int) {
        print("Hel-\(x)")
    }
}
class X:Z{
    func zoo(x:Int, z:Int)->Int {

        print("Hello-\(x) \(z)") 
        return z+x
    }
}
let s=X()

    s.zoo(x:50, z:24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает, но вы ничего не делаете с возвращаемым результатом, добавте`print(s.zoo(x:50, z:24))`

Comment: большое вам спасибо, за отзывчивость !!!